# Javascript / Jquery Submit Form without ID or Class, after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, form-submit

I have a website and we only have access to the .js files as the original PHP has been encoded and the developer has lost the source files.

What we're looking to do is submit the form on the page after the page loads.

Here is the form

```
<form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="username" class="form-control logininputs" id="input-login" placeholder="Username" value="usernamehere">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control logininputs" id="input-pass" placeholder="Password" value="passwordhere">
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 form_left">
            <div class="checkbox checkbox_new">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="rememberMe"> Remember me
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-ghost webtvloginprocess rippler rippler-default">LOGIN <i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner hideOnload" id="loginProcessIcon"></i></button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

I thought of doing this via JS however the form has no ID or class elements frustraitingly so I am stumped and cant seem to find a way to generically submit all forms. Further more this would create problems down the line as on every page the .JS file I place it in is requested, it would try and submit forms.

So option 2.

Can I force the submit button with the `class="btn btn-ghost webtvloginprocess rippler rippler-default"` to be "clicked" automatically after the page has loaded?

And how would I go about doing this so its the very last thing to happen?

Thanks

Comment: `$( document ).ready(function() { $('button[type="submit"]').click(); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() { // after page has loaded
  var but = document.querySelector(".webtvloginprocess.rippler.rippler-default");
  if (but) but.click();
})
```

This will possibly give a security error because it is not user initiated

Answer (score 0):

Put periods in front of every class name (instead of spaces) so you can select the button there with the query string

```
button.btn.btn-ghost.webtvloginprocess.rippler.rippler-default
```

and then just `click()` it, if it exists:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button.btn.btn-ghost.webtvloginprocess.rippler.rippler-default');
if (btn) btn.click();
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="username" class="form-control logininputs" id="input-login" placeholder="Username" value="usernamehere">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control logininputs" id="input-pass" placeholder="Password" value="passwordhere">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 form_left">
    <div class="checkbox checkbox_new">
      <label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="rememberMe"> Remember me
              </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-ghost webtvloginprocess rippler rippler-default">LOGIN <i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner hideOnload" id="loginProcessIcon"></i></button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Great answer ! however lacked the running after page has loaded I needed

Comment: You should generally be putting your scripts at the bottom of the `<body>` or give them the `defer` tag for that